# Position sticky overflow window blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

[image: question picture]

I have position sticky block that can be higher than window height and also can be less (depends on viewport). That means in some situations I cannot scroll to overflowed content. How to stick block from bottom if this block is bigger than window?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: There  are plenty of questions with high scores regarding HOW TO. It's kinda hard for the newbies to ask the right question when they lack the idea how to even try even after googling..

Comment: @Paulie_D I do not find anything wrong with the question, he is asking on how to approach the problem he is facing, the last line of his question states that. which is clearly what SO does, we share the knowledge and guide with an approach. I see no problem with the question and its really clear on both explanation as well as  the attached image.  If needed we can ask for his code.

Answer (score -1):

You should Probably try setting CSS `overflow:visible` to your body tag or the container tag, this should give you scroll bars up to the bottom of the sticky element

Do not try to alter sticky JS core file, this may effect the behavior of other sticky elements.

Paste your code here perhaps we can help better.

Comment: down voters should have the minimum manners to explain the reason in comments.